# How would I execute a Pivot Wider in Pandas? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot

I have a dataset, df:

```
Action      Date
Begin       3/16/2020 12:35:47 PM
End         3/16/2020 12:35:49 PM
Begin       3/16/2020 01:35:47 PM
End         3/16/2020 01:35:49 PM
```

Desired outcome:

```
Begin                       End
3/16/2020 12:35:47 PM       3/16/2020 12:35:49 PM
3/16/2020 01:35:47 PM       3/16/2020 01:35:49 PM
```

Structure:

```
Action  Date 
Begin   3/16/2020 12:35
End     3/16/2020 12:35
Begin   3/16/2020 13:35 
End     3/16/2020 13:35
```

I think this is a permute type problem, but not exactly sure. I have tried:

```
df2=df.pivot(columns='Action', values='Date')
```

This gives strange NAN values

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Action','Date']).unstack().reset_index()
```

Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: u shared an R data structure (```dput```) for a pandas problem?

Comment: sorry I am not sure how to share dput for pandas. Let me look this up

Comment: I have included the str(df)

Comment: @Lynn Could you please remove `structure` from the question? I could not establish its relevance to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pivot, and do a [bfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) on the End or a [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) on the Begin column :

```
(df.pivot(columns='Action',values='Date')
 .assign(End = lambda x:x.End.bfill())
 .dropna()
 .rename_axis(None,axis='columns')
)


           Begin                     End
0   3/16/2020 12:35:47 PM   3/16/2020 12:35:49 PM
2   3/16/2020 01:35:47 PM   3/16/2020 01:35:49 PM
```

Comment: I will look this up, but what exactly is the lambda for? (calculus foundation?/) what does it do?

Comment: One question. For the output I am not getting the AM/PM and the format is a little different. Does the data have to be converted first to Datetime?

Comment: Also, the code works for one of my datasets, but on the second dataset it keeps giving: 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Ended' , I researched this, yet, I do have this name as my dataframe

Comment: Ok this worked! But I had to an ffill on the other dataset. I am researching why this was the case. Why cant I apply 'bfill' to both?

Comment: This works now. Is there a way you could look at my recent question? I am trying to merge two datasets and have used this: pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="Connect", by='Start', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('20s'), direction='backward')